# How to avoid duplicate insert of ToolbarItem in Xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
protected override void OnAppearing(){
ToolbarItem itemStudy = new ToolbarItem {
Name = "Study",
Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary,
Command = new Command (() => Navigation.PushAsync (studyPage))
};
if (ToolbarItems.Count > 0) 
{
        ToolbarItems.RemoveAt(0);
}
ToolbarItems.Add (itemStudy);
}
```

This is my Code snipped on Xamarin.forms for adding Toolbaritem. Anyhow I don't think this is an elegant way and looking for better solution.
Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this to your page constructor:

```net
ToolbarItem itemStudy = new ToolbarItem {
Name = "Study",
Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary,
Command = new Command (() => Navigation.PushAsync (studyPage))
};
ToolbarItems.Add(itemStudy);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is quite easier than I expected!